# schematic symbol from power supply, two triangles pointing together

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, schematics, symbol

What does the symbol marked Z1 (two triangles pointing towards line) represent in this schematic?:

[image: Z1 in context]

This is coming from the reference design on page 10 of the LD7550-B pulse width modulator datasheet (Jan 2005 version). You can get the datasheet [here](http://www.aliot.com.ua/pdf/ld7550.pdf).  It's not written in the datasheet anywhere I can see, and in the table of part numbers the component value is written as "N/A".

Comment: Bidirectional TVS diode, I suppose from looking at the symbol only.

Comment: Seems to fit from the context.  I have another pretty naive question: in this schematic there are multiple places where two resistors are placed in series with nothing else connected, for example R1A and R1B, and also R2A and R2B.  Why would they do this instead of using a different resistor?  Just because of part availability, or perhaps to change the failure mode?

Comment: Two resistors in series have a higher voltage withstand/rating and/or power rating.

Comment: Because it is labelled with 'Z,' I think that is a back-to-back Zener diode. This is a type of TVS (transient voltage suppressor), so I am agreeing with Bence. Just providing more detail. If the part number is "N/A" I think that maybe it is not actually installed. Like they put it in the schematic just in case, but then found out they didn't need it in production.

Comment: Umm... I hope this is post a transformer because the dclink negative is tied to chassis which will me more than likely the neutral of the AC.

Comment: @Andy Yes, I guess it is the voltage rating -- R2A and R2B are 750 kOhm, 1/4 W, in a 1206 SMT package.  So it seems more likely that the voltage rating would be exceeded than the power.  Also, I can imagine that higher voltage rated resistors are more expensive than this solution, while higher power ratings are pretty normal.

Comment: @JonRB It's a reference design for a wall adapter / charger.  I think that "ground" for this circuit is practically defined by the negative side of C1, definitely isolated from the AC input.  There is a different symbol used for ground in the low-voltage region, and the two ground symbols are connected via is suppression capacitor CY1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Z' is often a designator for Transzorb, as is the symbol. However any SMPS I have ever seen normally use a 20mm MOV, which has a higher transient absorption rating. Confusing the issue even more is that 'Sidacs' use the same symbol, but are very expensive, often in the $20 to $40 price range.

Though I do not see values such as the rating of F1, this would be a low power circuit if only a Transzorb is being used.